# Matching Algorithm In SAS

Tags: sas

So I have this code which aims to left join a new interest rate based on its original maturity. for example, if the original maturity is 0.25 years, I want it to append on the interest rate for a 3 month rate.

The code looks like

```
data want;
set maturity;

retain tempMat tempRate;
i = 1;
do until(stop eq 1);
    set Maturity2 nobs = num point = i;
    diff = abs(sum(Maturity, -OriginalMaturity));
    if i eq 1 then
    do;
        tempMat = diff;
        tempRate = Base_Rate_New;
    end;
    else
    do;
        if i = num then
        do;
            stop = 1;
            Rate_ok = Base_Rate_New;
        end;
        else if diff gt tempMat then
        do;
            stop = 1;
            Rate_ok = tempRate;
        end;
        else
        do;
            tempMat = diff;
            tempRate = Base_Rate_New;
        end;
    end;
    i = i + 1;
end;
```

end;
run;

The two tables look like

```
data maturity;
input ID maturity base_rate;
datalines
1 0.25 1
2 0.5 1
3 0.6 2
4 0.3 3
5 1.2 1.2
6 1.5 2
7 2 3
8 3 1
9 1 0.5
;

data maturity2;
input originalmaturity base_rate_new;
datalines
0.25 2
0.5 3
0.75 1
1 3
;
run;
```

the dataset that I look to create would look like (after dropping all the extra variables

```
data want;
input ID maturity base_rate base_rate_new;
datalines
1 0.25 1 2
2 0.5 1 3
3 0.6 2 3
4 0.3 3 2
5 1.2 1.2 3
6 1.5 2 3
7 2 3 3
8 3 1 3
9 1 0.5 3
;
run;
```

The problem is that currently if the value exceeds the closer number, it still chooses the higher number. For example if it is 0.3 it would choose the 0.5 instead of 0.25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data want;
    set maturity;
    retain tempDiff Rate;
    do point=1 to n;
       set maturity2 nobs=n point=point;
       diff=abs(maturity-originalmaturity);
       if point=1 then do;
            tempDiff=diff;
            Rate=base_rate_new;
       end;
       else if diff<tempDiff then do;
           tempDiff=diff; 
           Rate=base_rate_new;
       end;
    end;
    drop diff tempDiff originalmaturity base_rate_new;
run;
```

Comment: Answers consisting only of code are not considered high quality answers; please include an explanation describing the solution (which is of more value than the code, even for questions such as this).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the second data set is sorted in ascending order, then you need to find the 2 rates that surround the value and check which is closer.  You have to handle the edge case where you have an exact match or when you get to the end of the second data set.

```
/*This assumes maturity2 is sorted ascending by originalmaturity*/
data want(keep=ID maturity originalmaturity base_rate base_rate_new);
set maturity;
stop = 0;
i = 1;

do until(stop eq 1);
    set Maturity2 nobs = num point = i;
/*  put _all_;*/
    if originalmaturity = maturity then do;
        output;
        stop = 1;
    end;

    else if originalmaturity < maturity then do;
        ldist = abs(originalmaturity - maturity);
        lbrn = base_rate_new;
    end;
    else if originalmaturity > maturity then do;
        hdist = abs(originalmaturity - maturity);
        if hdist > ldist then
            base_rate_new = lbrn;
        output;
        stop = 1;
    end;

    if num = i then do;
        output;
        stop = 1;
    end;
    i = i + 1;
end;
run;
```